# How to get all records having a passed string in text column

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

**What is the SQL query directly for this given use case:**

I want to get all records in the table that in their fields column which is of type text has pageTitle containing a specific string

**Table structure:**[image]

This query that I created `SELECT * FROM page_contents WHERE fields ILIKE '%"pageTitle":"%keyword%",%';`  won't do the job since it will search in the whole text after it encounters `"pageTitle":"` instead of stopping just after first occurance of `,"` if not found with pageTitle key. It will also return records that have keyword present anywhere after pageTitle for eg. for field like `'"trackCategory":"LP DE BF 01","pageTitle":"some page title","metaDescription":"some meta description",'` and consider keyword is `meta`. Then it will return this record with the field although we want to get records which have `"pageTitle":"%meta%","` for eg. for field like `'"trackCategory":"LP DE BF 01","pageTitle":"some meta title","metaDescription":"some description",'`

**Can it be achieved using direct SQL query with regex maybe or my only hope is to get all records and filter using javascript or my desired programming language?**

Comment: This search looks to be above a json field it is? if true you can use 
select * from public.page_contents where fields ->>'pageTitle' = 'Somepage'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer not exactly correct but works almost in every case:

```
SELECT * FROM page_contents WHERE fields ~* '"pageTitle":"[^"]*keyword';
```

Above query will only fail in case title has "(quote) present in it before our keyword

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp_like` as follows - see [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/5ymnwR/1)

```
SELECT * FROM page_contents WHERE regex_like(fields, '/pageTitle":"some page title"/')
```

Not sure if the / are necessary.